# equality of complex numbers: general case.

Tags: complex-numbers

Can someone help me to understand this definition (or proposition) for complex numbers equality, of the form $w=x+\xi y$. 
\begin{align*}
&\xi\text{ is a complex number such that } \Im(\xi)\neq0.\\
&\forall (a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{R^4}:\quad a+\xi b=c+\xi d\:\iff\:a=c \text{ and }b=d.\\
\end{align*}
I know that Two complex numbers are equal if and only if their real parts are equal and their imaginary parts are equal. but this a special case for $\xi=i$.

Comment: Does $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb C$?

Comment: what is the $z$ ?

Comment: @TheGreatSeo no in $\mathbb{R^4}$

Comment: @idm where is z?

Comment: @idm ah okay sorry

Comment: "$\xi$ is a complex number such that $\Im(z)\neq 0$.

Comment: @user161440 Then, are they quaternions?

Comment: @TheGreatSeo what is quaternions?

Comment: @TheGreatSeo Real numbers, 4 of them. (Seems obvious, no?)

Comment: Quaternion is a number system which extends $\Bbb C$. @Did Then, are they just vectors?

Comment: @TheGreatSeo Sorry but you are posting much too quickly to let your brain function, it seems. Read my previous comment SLOW-LY.

Comment: @Did Okay, $a,b,c,d$ in the post was edited to $(a,b,c,d)$, so $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R$... but while I'm typing, OP edited again. I think that $(a,b,c,d)$ is right, but what was the OP's purpose?

Comment: OP: Your last edit (overriding mine) reintroduced two basic mistakes in your question (see @TheGreatSeo's last comment). I reverted it. You can either continue this game, or start trying to think about what you write.

Comment: Is it a definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\xi=x+iy$, so:

$$a+\xi b=a+bx+byi$$

$$c+\xi d=c+dx+dyi$$

So you know that $a+b\xi=c+d\xi$ are equal if and only if  $a+bx=c+dx$ and $by=dy$. Next you know that $y \neq 0$, so you can divide by $y$ and get $b=d$. Next from first equation and $b=d$ you have $a+bx=c+bx$, so $a=c$.